# Update 200 multiple devices with the same specs at the same time?

Tags: ios, ipod-touch

I have 200 iPOD touch devices with the same specs. Currently, i am updating them one by one using Apple Configurator which does not require me to download the update multiple times. But, i still have to connect the devices and go through the update process one device at a time.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I still have the same issue with updating multiple devices.Any more ideas?

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to update the iOS directly on the iPod Touch (if you haven't disabled that option), otherwise you can speed up the process by connecting multiple devices to your Mac at once and update them in one go.

This can be done with multiple USB-Lightning cables plugged directly in to the computer, or by using USB hubs. A more expensive solution would be to buy a dedicated syncing/charging-station. These types of products often allow you to lock multiple iOS devices inside a cage or similar, and have them all easily charge and/or connected to a single Mac for syncing/updating. They come in various sizes for holding for example 4 devices, 16 devices, etc.

Comment: The is that, when i connect 2 or more devices to apple configurator, they will show up but i am able to update one device only. The other device is not clickable